# find the exact lenth of the curve $x= \frac{1}{3}(y^2+2)^\frac{3}{2} on\;1\leq y \leq2$

Tags: calculus

Find the exact length of the curve $x= \frac{1}{3}(y^2+2)^\frac{3}{2} on\;1\leq y \leq2$

We can find the length of curve using $\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}\right)^2}\space\space\text{d}x$ ...is this right

Comment: Yes, but note that $a$ and $b$ will be the limits of $x$ then. Or you can integrate with respect to $y$, which is much easier.

Comment: Your formula is right.  To use it you would first write $y$ as a function of $x$.  But since we already have $x$ written as a function of $y$, maybe using a similar integral with variable $y$ will be easier.

Answer (score 3):

Easier to integrate with respect to $y$ as follows.

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac12 (y^2+2)^{1/2} 2 y = y \sqrt{y^2+2} $$

$$1+\left (\frac{dx}{dy} \right )^2  = y^4 + 2 y^2 + 1 = (y^2+1)^2$$

The arc length is then

$$\int_1^2 dy \, (1+y^2) $$

which I assume you can do.